# How to make Android ACTION_CALL from the AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I need to make scheduled automated phone calls from my personal app/phone.  I use AlarmManager to schedule phone calls, but it only works if MyApp and the device is open/active.  I added a testing beep sound on the scheduled receiver, and it worked even the device was asleep (so, the scheduler is working).

Any idea how to make Intent.ACTION_CALL from a scheduler?  Or, how to re-open/focus MyApp's MainActive UI from the scheduler?

thx

Steve

```
// permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged" />

// setup alarm from the main activity
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent myAlarmIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1000, myAlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeFromUI, pendingIntent);

// make the call
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // this testing beep works even MyApp is closed or/and the device is asleep.
        ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP, 100);

        // the phone call only works if MyApp is open and the device is active.
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(("tel:123456789"))).setFlags(
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
        context.startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea how to make Intent.ACTION_CALL from a scheduler?

That is not possible on modern versions of Android.

> Or, how to re-open/focus MyApp's MainActive UI from the scheduler?

That too is not possible on modern versions of Android. [You cannot start activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts). The user might be relying on what presently is in the foreground (e.g., navigation app).

You could raise a high-priority notification, where the action of that notification triggers your `ACTION_CALL` request.